# Fazer Download automatico

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um projeto que usa o GoPhish para campanhas internas. Esta ferramenta tem um editor HTML que gera a página em questão. O problema que necessito que seja alocado nesta página um Download Automatico, porem se eu coloco um href ou windows location para  o download automatico, não funciona. Existe alguma função em Jquery que ao acessar a página faça download automatico sem precisar clicar em algum botão?

A ferramenta GoPhish não aceita linguagens como PHP.

Comment: Um aqruivo TXT, pode ter interação do usuário sem problemas, mas precisava desse download. O projeto é justamente para concientização de segurança.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o atributo **[download](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)** do HTML5. Basta inserir um evento `onclick` e chama-lo no carregamento da página:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#baixar").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="baixar" href="nome.txt" onclick="this.click()" download="umnomediferente.txt">Baixar TXT</a>
```

Veja que coloquei um nome diferente do original no atributo `download`. Caso queira que o nome seja o mesmo, basta deixar apenas `download`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#baixar").click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="baixar" href="nome.txt" onclick="this.click()" download>Baixar TXT</a>
```

Comment: Boa, é isso mesmo. Obrigado por mais uma ajuda.